# Looping through variables in a Windows Form

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, loops

I'm writing a little VB.Net code to populate text and picture boxes on a windows form from an array, but this seems a rather inefficient way of doing things:

```
Item1_TB.Text = FormatCurrency(Items(0).Item_Cost, 2)
Item2_TB.Text = FormatCurrency(Items(1).Item_Cost, 2)
Item3_TB.Text = FormatCurrency(Items(2).Item_Cost, 2)
Item4_TB.Text = FormatCurrency(Items(3).Item_Cost, 2)
Item5_TB.Text = FormatCurrency(Items(4).Item_Cost, 2)
Item6_TB.Text = FormatCurrency(Items(5).Item_Cost, 2)

Item1.Image = Image.FromFile(Items(0).Item_Image)
Item2.Image = Image.FromFile(Items(1).Item_Image)
Item3.Image = Image.FromFile(Items(2).Item_Image)
Item4.Image = Image.FromFile(Items(3).Item_Image)
Item5.Image = Image.FromFile(Items(4).Item_Image)
Item6.Image = Image.FromFile(Items(5).Item_Image)
```

Is there any way I can drop this inside a for loop and use something similar to:

```
Item[i]_TB.Text = FormatCurrency(Items(i).Item_Cost, 2)
Item[i].Image = Image.FromFile(Items(i).Item_Image)
```

Comment: You could find controls dynamically by name but I wouldn't recommend it. You also could store your controls in an array.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll do a little research and give it a go.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through all the controls in the parent control. Dont know if that is your form or panel or something like that.

```
dim tb as textbox
dim i as integer
for each o as object in me.controls
 if typeof(o is textbox) then
  tb = ctype(o,textbox)
  i = tb.name.substring(4,1)
  tb.Text = FormatCurrency(Items(i).Item_Cost, 2)
 end if
next
```

Comment: +1 though I suggest you revise your post to clarify that the parent control vs. container. (That they are the same in this case)

Answer (score 0):

Placing all the controls in similar array's allows looping.

Can use a format like this...

```
Dim ctls() as control={Item1_TB, Item2_TB, etc... }
For iQ as integer = 0 to ubound(ctls)
    ctls(iQ).Text = .FormatCurrency(Items(iQ).Item_Cost, 2)
Next iQ
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little sketchy because it assumes you'll never have more than nine control (i.e. 1 through 9) and it assumes that the TextBox and PictureBox controls are all treated the same way. If you have additional TextBox or PictureBox controls on the form this won't work.

```
For Each control In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf control Is TextBox Then
        Dim txt As TextBox = CType(control, TextBox)
        Dim index As Integer = CInt(txt.Name.Substring(4, 1))

        txt.Text = FormatCurrency(Items(index - 1).Item_Cost, 2)
    ElseIf TypeOf control Is PictureBox Then
        Dim pic As PictureBox = CType(control, PictureBox)
        Dim index As Integer = CInt(pic.Name.Substring(4, 1))

        pic.Image = Image.FromFile(Items(index - 1).Item_Image)
    End If
Next
```

It could be made to work for more than nine controls but the `Name.Substring` call would need to be made more intelligent.

UPDATE

I just thought of another option. Both `TextBox` and `PictureBox` have a `Tag` property. You could use that to denote the index. If the `Tag` property isn't set you just skip it.

```
For Each control In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf control Is TextBox Then
        Dim txt As TextBox = CType(control, TextBox)

        If Not txt.Tag Is Nothing Then
            Dim index As Integer = CInt(txt.Tag)

            txt.Text = FormatCurrency(Items(index).Item_Cost, 2)
        End If
    ElseIf TypeOf control Is PictureBox Then
        Dim pic As PictureBox = CType(control, PictureBox)

        If Not pic.Tag Is Nothing Then
            Dim index As Integer = CInt(pic.Name.Substring(4, 1))

            pic.Image = Image.FromFile(Items(index).Item_Image)
        End If
    End If
Next
```

The advantage of this is that you never have to change you code if you add a new TextBox/PictureBox pair to the window. Just add the controls, set the `Tag` property to the index of the `Items` array that should be used to populate each of them and away you go.

Answer (score 0):

The most robust way of doing that IMHO would be to make your code aware that there's logical ranges of controls in your UI.

```
Dim textboxesRange As TextBox()
Dim pictureboxesRange As PictureBox()
```

In your constructor, you will have to init these ranges.

```
Public Sub New()
    // ...

    textboxesRange = {Item1_TB, Item2_TB, Item3_TB, Item4_TB, Item5_TB, Item6_TB }
    pictureboxesRange = {Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4, Item5, Item6 }

    // ...
End Sub
```

Afterwards, you'll be able to loop through these arrays:

```
For i = 0 To textboxesRange.Length - 1
    textboxesRange(i).Text = FormatCurrency(Items(i).Item_Cost, 2)
Next

For i = 0 To pictureboxesRange.Length - 1
    pictureboxesRange(i).Image = Image.FromFile(Items(i).Item_Image)
Next
```

This way **you make your code aware of the reality that there are controls which are related**, which hardens your app. From this point on, it becomes easier for you not only to initiate values but also change or reset them (should you need to). You will also become able to manipulate these controls as a logical group for different things (hiding, moving, etc) in a way that is both dynamic, robust, elegant and efficient.

While using control's `Name` or `Tag` properties could very well work too, it's bad practice IMHO, as these aren't dedicated to solve such a specific problem. Try never relying on those.